# addChild custom class AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop, addchild

This is the class I am trying instantiate into my main class:

```
public class Character extends Sprite {

    [Embed(source='../lib/front1.svg')]
    private var front1Class:Class;
    private var crosshair:Sprite = new front1Class ();

    public function Character() {
        trace("started");
        Mouse.hide();

        crosshair.scaleX = 5;
        crosshair.scaleY = 5;
        this.addChild(crosshair);

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MrEveryFrame);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click);
    }


    private function click(evt:MouseEvent):void {
        trace("clicked @ " + evt.stageX + "," + evt.stageY);

    }
    public function MrEveryFrame(e:Event):void
    {
        crosshair.x = mouseX - 15;
        crosshair.y = mouseY - 15;


    }

}
```

When I set it to the document class, it works fine.

However... when I make THIS my document class and try to call it from there:

```
public class Shell extends Sprite
{


    private var character:Sprite = new Character ();


    public function Shell() 
    {

        addChild(character);


    }


}
```

It breaks, and no longer shows the sprite object (though it does erase the mouse pointer).

What's the deal here? You can't instantiate custom sprite or movieclip classes into a DisplayObject class???

Comment: Do a trace inside Character after adding the crosshair: trace("stage exists? "+stage);  It's probably null at instantiation.

Comment: If you're extending Sprite then in your constructor you need to call `super();` to get everything that belongs to Sprite set up.  So, right before your line `trace("started");` add the line `super();` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stage is `null` in the constructor. That only works when your class is the Document Class, as you found out yourself. So change your constructor like this:

```
public function Character() {
    trace("started");
    Mouse.hide();

    crosshair.scaleX = 5;
    crosshair.scaleY = 5;
    this.addChild(crosshair);

    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
}

private function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void
{

    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MrEveryFrame);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click);
}
```

Adding the listener will access the stage only after the stage is known, and it's no longer `null`

Comment: This fixed my issue, not sure why the handlers were killing the display of my sprite, but works now, thanks